# Stack Exchange "Top Users" page should show usernames instead

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com, reputation-leagues, top-users

The Stack Exchange "Top Users" page looks like this:

[image]

The caption below each user avatar in the table says "week", "month", etc.

Shouldn't the caption instead say their username, and the terms "week", "month", etc. would be headings of the table?

Larger usernames can be dealt with like this: for example, the username "jon skeet is top user" can be shown as "jon skeet ...". That would still be more informative and less redundant than the current scheme of things.